# in python how the count method is working without the string

Tags: python, string, methods

My question is that why python giving the ans is 7 without having the string in the count method

```
txt = "banana"
x = txt.count("")
print(x)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

Comment: Actually, the string is there! It's kind of treated like `"-b-a-n-a-n-a-".count("-")` in this case.

Comment: the empty string which you have used is basically the substring of every string and the `count()` method returns the substring's occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

According to python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), if the string parameter is empty, the count method returns the length of the original string + 1.

> If sub is empty, returns the number of empty strings between characters which is the length of the string plus one.

Answer (score -3):

It can be **fix** by passing `' '` instead of `''`:

```py
>>> 'banana'.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
>>> 'banana'.count('')
7
>>> len('banana' ) + len('!')
7
>>> 'banana'.count( ' ')
0
>>> 'banana'.swapcase().count('B')
1
```

### Explained

Q: Why it's printing the 7?

A: The len of an input string ("bnanana" == 6) + one extra character (1) --> total: `7`

Comment: why it is printing 7

Comment: so, 7 is my lucky number

Comment: aside from that, the len of string (6) + one extra char (1)

Comment: This answer is not relevant at all to the question

Comment: @LiorV I added an explani section, so now it is more relevant. thanks!